# Hide Resources Files from Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, encryption, resources, quartz-composer

I am finalising my new osx app.

It uses a QC Composition as a banner everything works good however, I am trying to find the way to hide or encrypt the resource folder and make the composition used not visible to users.

I have tried to add (.folder) a dot before my QC folder in Xcode to make the file hidden but is not working as it is not a system file.

Any Idea how to achieve this?

I have used Quartz builder before and I can see that when I use it to create an app over a QC composition the file is encrypted and not visible if the user open the resources folder "Show Package Contents.

How can I do this by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encrypted means it's done by code. I don't know how to do that, but simply hiding the file would already help.

And hide a file can be done easily through Terminal !